# How do I get my modal to close after clicking "Save Changes?" And how do I update my appointmentDate in my database after clicking Save Changes?

Tags: model-view-controller, modal-dialog

Written here is my appointmentlist page. What I want to happen is that whenever I press the "Reschedule button" a modal pops up with a date picker, this date picker should then be updated in my database after clicking savechanges. I also want the Appointment Date and Time get updates on screen after clicking save changes. Also, my Modal does not close whenever I click Save.

```
@{
    ViewData["Registered"] = true;
    Layout = "_Layout";
    var pediaId = UserManager.GetUserId(User);

    var appointmentList = await BabyPediaContext.Appointments
        .Include(x => x.Parent)
        .Include(x => x.Child)
        .Include(x => x.AppointmentType)
        .Where(x => x.Pedia.Id == pediaId).ToListAsync();
    var message = ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["message"]; }

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) {
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        @message
    </div> }

@if (appointmentList.Any()) {
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">
            <p class="text-center fw-bold text-primary">
                Appointments
            </p>
        </h1>

        <table class="table m-2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Guardian's Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Child's Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Appointment Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date and Time</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var i in appointmentList)
                {
                    DateTime appointmentDateTime = DateTime.Parse($"{i.AppointmentDate} {i.AppointmentTime}");
                    TimeSpan timeUntilAppointment = appointmentDateTime - DateTime.Now;

                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" class="">
                            @i.Parent.FirstName @i.Parent.LastName
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @i.Child.Username
                        </th>
                        <th id="consultation-type-@i.Id">
                            @i.AppointmentType.Name
                        </th>
                        <th id="date-time-@i.Id">
                            @i.AppointmentDate : @i.AppointmentTime
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <a href="/pedia/appointment/@i.Id" class="btn-success btn"><i class="bi bi-chat-fill"></i> Chat</a>
                            <a href="/prescribe/@i.Id" class="btn-success btn"><i class="bi bi-file-break-fill"></i> Prescribe</a>
                            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rescheduleModal-@i.Id">
                                Reschedule
                            </button>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="rescheduleModal-@i.Id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="rescheduleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="rescheduleModalLabel">Reschedule Appointment</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            @{
                                                int cutoffHour = 17;
                                                int cutoffMinute = 0;
                                                bool disableToday = DateTime.Now.Hour >= cutoffHour && DateTime.Now.Minute >= cutoffMinute;
                                                string minDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                                if (!disableToday)
                                                {
                                                    minDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                                }
                                            }
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                                    <input id="birthdate-id-@i.Id" type="date" name="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" aria-required="true" min="@minDate" />
                                                    <label for="birthdate-id-@i.Id">Date of Visit</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <script>
                                                const birthdateInput = document.getElementById("birthdate-id-@i.Id");
                                                birthdateInput.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
                                                    event.preventDefault();
                                                });
                                                birthdateInput.addEventListener("change", function () {
                                                    const selectedDate = new Date(this.value);
                                                    const yesterday = new Date();
                                                    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
                                                    yesterday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                                                    if (selectedDate.getTime() <= yesterday.getTime()) {
                                                        this.value = "";
                                                        alert("Please select a date after yesterday.");
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            </script>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveChangesButton-@i.Id">Save changes</button>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <a href="/pediaappointment/delete/@i.Id" id="cancel-button-@i.Id" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel this appointment?')">Cancel Appointment</a>

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS and Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script> } else {
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        No parent has requested an appointment yet!
    </div> }

<script>
     
    function closeModal(appointmentId) {
        $('#rescheduleModal-').modal('hide');
    }

    // Event listener for the "Save changes" button
    $(document).ready(function () {
        @foreach (var i in appointmentList)
        {
            <script>
                $('#saveChangesButton-@i.Id').on('click', function () {
                    closeModal('@i.Id');
                }); </script> }
    }); </script>
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to save it in your browser?

Comment: I don't get any response from the system

Comment: Is your Dev Tools open while you test?